# For nonzero vectors $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^2$, where $u\neq v$, is the length of the projection of $v$ along $u$ always less than the length of $v$.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, mathematical-physics

> For all nonzero vectors $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^2$, where $u\neq v$, the length of the projection of $v$ along $u$ is less than the length of $v$.

This is a true/false question and when I said true it was marked as wrong. Now I am looking for some help/clarification.

I've tried this two different ways but I need to justify my reasoning. If I choose $v=[13;6]$ and $u= [16;0]$ then it holds true because my projection is only $[13;0]$.

Thinking what if my u was shorter I picked a vector of $[12;0]$ which then gave me a projection of $[13;0]$ again. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: True/False cna unfortunately degenerate into a game of trying to trick people. Example: $u=-v$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: True or false: I used to think that you would eventually think that I will frequently think that you had thought me a fool?

Comment: The reference has no referant. It's just a joke relating to your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be equal; consider for example if $v$ is a multiple of $u$.

Comment: but, if I'm told u is not equal to v. . . hmm he didn't say anything about scaler multiples so that very well could be the trick here. Ill give it another shot and see what I get.

Comment: For vectors $u$ and $v$, the vector projection of $v$ along $u$ is $(u\cdot v)u/|u|^2$, and so has length $|u\cdot v|/|u|$ (since $|u/|u||=1$). Since $|u\cdot v|\leq |u||v|$, the length of the projection is less than or equal to $|v|.$ So equality is the best we can do, and we have equality precisely when we have equality in $|u\cdot v|\leq|u||v|$, which is when $u$ and $v$ are multiples of each other. So it's the only possible trick here.

Comment: Yeah, Im seeing this now. I just ran it with some sample numbers which in this case would mean that it could be considered false because v would now be equal to u and not less than.

That said, how the hell do I make my symbols appear like you do? Ill begin searching but a point in where to look would be nice.

Comment: @Threshold: search the help system and/or the Intertubes for MathJax. If you've used $\LaTeX$, or any other $\TeX$ variant, it will look very, very familiar.